# Fill QTableWidget quickly

Tags: qt, filesystems

I'm creating a very simple disk space analyzer that shows ocupied size of every file in specific foder and its subfolders. I'm using QStack to store paths and QTableWidget for showing next information (File Name, File Path, File Size and Last Modified Date). First of all I use QDirIterator to fill QStack, then in different thread I get necessary information about file by QFileInfo and add row in QTableWidget with this information. Populating QStack is quick but filling QTableWidget is very slow. The question is how can I boost speed of filling QTableWidget.

dialog.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QStack>
#include "mythread.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();
    MyThread *mThread;
    QStack<QString> *fileStack;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

public slots:
    void onFileAdded(QString file);

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDateTime>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "File name" << "File Path" << "File Size (KB)" << "Last Modified Date");
    fileStack = new QStack<QString>();

    ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);

    mThread = new MyThread(this);
    connect(mThread, SIGNAL(fileAdded(QString)), this, SLOT(onFileAdded(QString)));
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
    delete mThread;
    delete fileStack;
}

void Dialog::onFileAdded(QString file) {
    QFileInfo fileInfo;
    fileInfo.setFile(file);
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1,
                             0,
                             new QTableWidgetItem(fileInfo.fileName()));

    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1,
                             1,
                             new QTableWidgetItem(fileInfo.filePath()));
    int sss = fileInfo.size() / 1024;
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item->setData(Qt::EditRole, sss);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1,
                             2,
                             item);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1,
                             3,
                             new QTableWidgetItem(fileInfo.lastModified().toString()));
    //ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
    //ui->tableWidget->resizeRowsToContents();
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString dirname = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Select a Directory"), QDir::currentPath());
    ui->lineEdit->setText(dirname);
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QDirIterator it(ui->lineEdit->text(), QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        fileStack->push(it.next());
    }
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Completed");
    msgBox.exec();
    mThread->dir = fileStack;
    mThread->start();
}
```

Comment: Why do not you use QTreeView with QFileSysteModel?

Comment: @eyllanesc Anyway program must show where large files are located.

Comment: QTableWidget is very slow, has too many things, so you get that behavior, if you indicate how to select the directory or directories that you want to show in the table we could give you a better approach.